# Issue with Comparison operator with an application

Tags: java

Currently, I am stuck on a problem with operator use.

When I try to use Code 1, the program runs smoothly.
But when I try to use Code 2, it throws a "Concurrent Modification" error for a few of the files, but not for all.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Code 1:

```
if (variable1 == variable2) {
    //some logic 
}
```

Code 2:

```
double result = Math.abs(variable1 - variable2);
if (result < somevalue) {
    //same logic as above
}
```

Comment: is this pseudo code? it may be helpful to see the code snippet in its entirety

Comment: It is hard to understand from your code. but as per my understanding, your logic is executed when it's not supposed to which indicates your condition check has a flaw.

Comment: Yes, It is pseudo-code. The code cannot be shown. The condition is correct and all the statements get executed for that condition. These statements run for thousands of time in a loop but never produces an error for larger number of times.